# Tesseract OCR In monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, ocr

How do I implement the Tesseract OCR in a monotouch application for Iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to have the library *ported* to iOS and available as a **static** library. That where Vikas' answer ([Pocket-PCR](https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR)) might comes handy (but I have not tried it).

Next you'll need to create C# bindings to the library.

When the API is exports C functions you can use *normal* .NET pinvokes, i.e. using [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attributes.

When an Objective-C API is provided then you can create bindings using the `btouch` tool. [Instructions](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types) are available on the MonoTouch web site.

However (and this looks to be the case for [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)) it's a bit more complex for C++ libraries. You'll either need to first create a C (or Objective-C) library that export the feature you need and them bind your own API.

Answer (score 1):

To build the tesseract library, download the source code and compile apropriately for the iPhone (arm processor). Add the library to the XCode project and build.
go this link and try ........

https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR

Comment: Yeah...nice one but this may help who is looking for iPhone.

Comment: Vikas, please include information from the link; otherwise this answer is useless if that link gets moved or dies.