# Tesseract OCR in Monotouch - Is it possible?

Tags: xamarin.ios, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract or any OCR tool in my app that is written in Monotouch. I have been unable to figure out how to combine the two. Does anyone have any information or possibly a tutorial on how to do this process?

Comment: Yes - there are several SO questions directly addressing this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648250/tesseract-ocr-in-monotouch and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951080/tesseract-ocr-camera-ios

Comment: I saw both of those posts and neither really say how to accomplish this. I am new at this and from those posts and what I found on the interent, it seems like only one person has even figured this out.

Comment: I guess my main thing is... Not exactly sure how to go from the Tesseract code to using it in my MonoTouch project. The Binding part, maybe might be the issue.